# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?)

Tags: angular, reflect

I want to create Angular application without CLI.
After that I get an error:

**Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).**

Project contains couple files, main of this is:

• main.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './modules/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

• component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `Hello World`
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

• module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppComponent } from "../components/app.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I search on StackOverflow before, but I can't found solution.
Similar error occur when someone wants to inject service without @Injectable decorator. In my case I don't have any service, so that am afraid nobody has the same error.

Angular CLI is so simple to start project, but only when you want setup project without generator, you know what parts are necessary to create during bootstrap application.

Answer (score 21):

1. Install core-js by command:

   ```
   npm i core-js
   ```
2. Add in `main.ts` file:

   ```
   import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
   import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
   ```

*Btw. I have spent a whole day to resolve this.*

Comment: can you provide full code for example publish on github? i am trying to archive same test app and get same error

Comment: You can do it, when remove core-js dependency. Currently my project is grown and I cannot published it.

Comment: can you look at this  https://github.com/gdbd/Angular_no_cli   ?
the code is almost same but i get error "Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?)."

Comment: wtf. I had seen debugging something was pointing to reflect. But I'd never thought about polyfills

Comment: Paths have changed in newest version of core-js (3.0.1). I had to use `import 'core-js/es/reflect'; import 'core-js/stable/reflect'; import 'core-js/features/reflect';`

Answer (score 3):

The current answer is outdated:

1 - Install core-js doing:

```
npm install core-js
```

2 - Add in your `main.ts` file ( this is the new part):

```
import "core-js/es/reflect";
import "core-js/stable/reflect";
import "core-js/features/reflect";
```

(Edition is not allwed on the previous answer)